# form fields added via javascript don't pass data

Tags: javascript

Didn't find any question like this, I have a form with a single set of fields, and adding more if the user clicks a button. I'm making those fields the same as the first set, and using name='array[]' for all sets of fields.

Anyway, when I submit the form, with the javascript generated fields along with the original fields, only the values in the original set of fields is being passed.

This is in codeigniter.

I can't pass all the code but there is the generated html in pastebin and I will paste the php/ javascript bits that pertain to this issue.

```
<tr id="add_dependents">
    <td class="tim-dependents-table-cell">
        <?php $data = array('class' => 'tim-dependents-table-contents', 'name' => 'dependent_names[]', 'id' => 'dependent_names_1', 'value' => $dep_names[0]);
        echo form_input($data);
        ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <?php $data = array('class' => 'tim-dependents-table-contents', 'name' => 'dependent_ssns[]', 'id' => 'dependent_ssns_1', 'value' => $dep_ssns[0]);
        echo form_input($data);
        ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <?php $data = array('class' => 'tim-dependents-table-contents', 'type' => 'date', 'name' => 'dependent_dobs[]', 'id' => 'dependent_dobs_1', 'value' => $dep_dobs[0]);
        echo form_input($data);
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="red"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then I'm creating more fields, if the user clicks a button, with this function:

```
if (typeof count === 'undefined') {
        var count = 2;
    }

    function insertDependent() {
        $("#add_dependents").after("<tr id='dependents_row_" + count + "'>" +
            "<td><input type='text' id='dependent_names_" + count + "' name='dependent_names[]' /></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' id='dependent_ssns_" + count + "' name='dependent_ssns[]'/></td>" +
            "<td><input type='date' id='dependent_dobs_" + count + "' name='dependent_dobs[]'/></td>" +
            "<td><a href='#' onclick='deleteRow(" + count + ")' class='red'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></td>" +
            "</tr>");
        count++;
    }
```

That part is working, and generating fields that look to me like they should.

Then the code in the controller that's taking these fields in particular. Not sharing all the code that works, only the part that is not:

```
if(!empty($this->input->post('dependent_names'))) {
                $data['dependent_names'] = $this->input->post('dependent_names');
                $data['dependent_ssns'] = $this->input->post('dependent_ssns');
                $data['dependent_dobs'] = $this->input->post('dependent_dobs');
            }
```

The problem is on the page though, before it gets to the controller. The payload from submitting the page includes the 'permanent' set of fields but not any data in javascript generated fields.

What should happen, is the fields being created via javascript should be submitted with data just like the 'permanent' set of fields.

Comment: How is the form submitted?

Comment: It's submitted via form action="controller/method" method="post". I've tested the form many times, it works, does what it should. Just this part isn't working.

Comment: I'm not positive that it's the cause of the problem, but element IDs need to be unique.  You are creating your form fields with the same ID each time.

Comment: Yes, true. I had them generating different ones too, and that didn't work which is why I changed them to the same. I'll go back to unique and see if anything changes,

Comment: Yeah following up on the above I just changed them back to where each ID is unique like dependent_names_1, dependent_names_2, etc. I'll leave it that way if it's more correct, but still not working.

Comment: "the fields created via javascript are not passing data."  How are you confirming this?  Are you viewing the posted data in your browser's network inspector?

Comment: what I'm doing is submitting the form without some required data, so it posts back to the page with the data. then dumping that variable on the page. might be a little clunky but it works (usually). is there a better way?

Comment: I suggest doing what I said.  View the payload of the post.  That will tell you if those fields are actually posted.  If they are, then it is not an issue with the the form, but what you're doing with the data on the server.

Comment: Got it, using chrome dev tools, found the headers. Shows the first set of fields but not the data in the fields generated via javascript.

Comment: Are you sure the added elements are included in the form?  I mean, placed between <form>...</form>

Comment: Yes, they are included between the form tags.

Comment: Why do you have multiple loops instead of just `$dependent_names = $this->input->post('dependent_names')` ???

Comment: If the browser isn't submitting the values of those elements, they aren't in the form as @CharlesEF said, or you're doing some kind of JS form submission that isn't taking all the form elements into account.

Comment: You are right, in this case it works. I don't recall why I did it that way. I'll change it above. thanks

Comment: But it doesn't fix the issue above.

Comment: It's php submission, action post and going to the controller/method. And yes the fields are inside the form tags.

Comment: Oddly when I view source the closing form tag is in the right place. When I use chrome dev tools 'Elements' section it shows it closing close to the top of the form. Doesn't make sense to me and like I said, the form is working, just these added fields aren't.

Comment: There are fields above the added fields, and below the added fields, that are working properly.

Comment: it sounds like you've left out alot of the code, and I understand why. however i have a feeling your issue is in these left out sections. if you could simplify the code removing dependencies .etc. and post the full html code on pastebin or what have you (enough to run on our systems) so we can diagnose the problem. otherwise it is just a guessing game.

Comment: OK I created a pastebin with the generated source of the page. https://pastebin.com/a5PeN73s . Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I had the opening form tag nested in a way that some div elements opened before it and closed after it.

In other words I had this:

```
<div>

    <form action="" etc>

</div>

    </form>
```

I moved the form tag higher up on the page, like this:

```
<form action="" etc>

    <div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Funny thing is the whole thing worked, except for the javascript fields. I'm going to remove PHP and codeigniter since this is a straight javascript issue and I hope some expert can explain.

Glad it's working now but I still don't know the deeper 'why'.

Thanks to commenters who tried to help.